# regex a line from file using python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to regex data from a line in the file, and failing. I tried to use [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)
but failed there as well.
The code I came up with is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#line to be parsed:
# 1.  Ni  type=1   np=1001 r1=1.0E-05  rnp=-1.35602175  pfile=Ni1.pot
#To parse is
# 1   Ni                                                      Ni1.pot     
import re
f1=open("file.str","r")
pattern=r'(\d+)\s+(.*)\s+ type=(\d+)*\s pfile=(.*)'
count=[]; atype=[]; pots=[]
for line in f1:
  match=re.search(pattern,line)
  if match:
    count.append(int(match.group(1)))
    atype.append((match.group(2)))
    apots.append((match.group(3)))

print(count)
```

Can anyone kindly show what error I am making?

Comment: Could you please clarify what the actual expected output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change the pattern like this

```
pattern = r'(\d+)\.\s*(.*)\s+ type=(\d+).* pfile=(.*)'
```

because, there is a dot after the first number, so we have

```
(\d+)\.
```

after that there can be 0 more whitespace characters,

```
(\d+)\.\s*
```

then we capture the word, `Ni` with

```
(\d+)\.\s*(.*)
```

and then there can be 1 or more spaces, followed by `type=<numbers>`

```
(\d+)\.\s*(.*)\s+ type=(\d+)
```

after that there can be any characters followed by `pfile=<filename>`. We capture that with

```
(\d+)\.\s*(.*)\s+ type=(\d+).* pfile=(.*)
```

and since you are capturing four items,

```
count, atype, pots, files = [], [], [], []
...
    pots.append(match.group(3))
    files.append(match.group(4))

print(count, atype, pots, files)
# [1], ['Ni'], ['1'], ['Ni1.pot']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't match the dot after the first number, and you don't match the other arguments after type= and before pfile=. This should work:

```
pattern=r'(\d+).\s+(.*?)\s+type=(\d+).*\s+pfile=(.*?)\s*'
```